# When or in which case should i use RepositoryProvider in Flutter Bloc?

Tags: flutter, repository-pattern, bloc, provider, flutter-bloc

I was fetch data from api without RepositoryProvider, but I saw RepositoryProvider on documentation.
What is difference? or Should I use for data?

When I used RepositoryProvider, I couldnt change state. For example, I tried using RefreshIndicator but state didn't rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

RepositoryProvider is a Flutter widget which provides a repository to its children via RepositoryProvider.of(context). It is used as a dependency injection (DI) widget so that a single instance of a repository can be provided to multiple widgets within a subtree. BlocProvider should be used to provide blocs whereas RepositoryProvider should only be used for repositories.

RepositoryProvider Usage

```
class WeatherRepository {
  WeatherRepository({
    MetaWeatherApiClient? weatherApiClient
  }) : _weatherApiClient = weatherApiClient ?? MetaWeatherApiClient();

  final MetaWeatherApiClient _weatherApiClient;

  Future<Weather> getWeather(String city) async {
    final location = await _weatherApiClient.locationSearch(city);
    final woeid = location.woeid;
    final weather = await _weatherApiClient.getWeather(woeid);
    return Weather(
      temperature: weather.theTemp,
      location: location.title,
      condition: weather.weatherStateAbbr.toCondition,
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
void main() {
  runApp(WeatherApp(weatherRepository: WeatherRepository()));
}
```

---

```
class WeatherApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const WeatherApp({
            required WeatherRepository weatherRepository,
            Key? key, 
  })
      : _weatherRepository = weatherRepository,
        super(key: key);

  final WeatherRepository _weatherRepository;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RepositoryProvider.value(
      value: _weatherRepository,
      child: BlocProvider(
        create: (_) => ThemeCubit(),
        child: WeatherAppView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
class WeatherPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => WeatherCubit(context.read<WeatherRepository>()),
      child: WeatherView(),
    );
  }
}
```

more info in [documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=repositoryprovider). but in general repository it is about data, and bloc - it is about state management.